# How to login customers on react native Shopify app

Tags: api, authentication, shopify, admin

I am working on Shopify react-native app, I am able to create customer using create customer rest API, and also able to login that customer on web store but I am facing issue in customer login on react-native app.

I've read the documentation and found that there is an option of mupltipass for creating customer in Shopify plus, but I have basic Shopify plan.

Is there any admin rest API or any other way to login customer on mobile app except multipass.

Comment: Hello,
Have you got any feedback ? i'm facing same isuse.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate [mobile-buy-sdk-ios](https://github.com/Shopify/mobile-buy-sdk-ios) and [mobile-buy-sdk-android](https://github.com/Shopify/mobile-buy-sdk-android) than you need to access platform api using native modules for android https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android and ios https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios